# apache.poi.HSSF

Tags: java

Есть некий excel(.xls) документ.
Для его проверки использую apache.poi.HSSF

В данном документе у некоторых колонок есть выпадающий список(см. Изображение).

Вопрос: есть метод(ы)/способы у HSSF с помощью которых можно узнать, какие есть элементы в выпадающем списке? Можно и другие способы)
В случае с картинкой - я должен получить: строка 1, строка 2, строка 3.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UP:

почитал что есть HSSFAutoFilter т.е. sheet1.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("B1")); Но в данном случае мы же сет делаем для заполнения? А нужно считать данные.

Comment: почитал что есть 
HSSFAutoFilter

т.е.
 AutoFilter filter = sheet1.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("B1"));
Но в данном случае мы же сет делаем для заполнения? А нужно считать.

Comment: дополняйте свой вопрос, а не пишите в комментариях, пожалуйста.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin, обновил. Извиняюсь, с оформлением еще не разобрался.

Answer (score 0):

Для XSSF насколько я помню можно было сделать так:

```
final CTAutoFilter filter = ((XSSFSheet)sheet1).getCTWorksheet().getAutoFilter();
if(filter != null) {
    final CellRangeAddress area = CellRangeAddress.valueOf(filter.getRef());
}
```

По идее для HSSF должно работать, если привести к HSSFSheet.

Логика простая - получаем регион на который ссылается автофильтр и далее получаем из него данные.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую отпишусь.

Comment: пока не получилось, при попытке привести HSSF к XSSF ругается(что наверно логично).

Comment: Все даже проще чем казалось. CTAutoFilter af = sheet.getAutoFilter(); CellRangeAddress area = af.getRangeAddress();

Comment: А получить его можно допустим так final XSSFSheet xssfSheet = (XSSFSheet) sheet;
            Field fWorksheet = XSSFSheet.class.getDeclaredField("worksheet");
            fWorksheet.setAccessible(true);
            CTWorksheet worksheet = (CTWorksheet) fWorksheet.get(xssfSheet);

Comment: спасибо попробую, отпишусь.